# TableViews and separate columns

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to get to columns in my app. 
The first column will be used as a table of contents while the second - will be user as table with headers and content.

For example - when user clicks on item 3 inside left column - the right column is smoothly scrolled to item 3. Also I want this columns to have separate scrolling. So when I scroll left column - right column stays still.

[image]

I know that I can build two separate TableViews: left one will be with items and the right one will be with sections and cells for content.

1) Is this the right way for that case? Maybe I should use CollectionViews?
2) If I will use separate TableViews - how can I get smooth scrolling in right TableView when Item is selected in left TableView?

Comment: Two Table Views would be fine. You can use Collection Views if your content would benefit from Collection View capabilities (no way to answer that without being inside your head). As far as "smooth scrolling" ... if `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` doesn't give you satisfactory results, then you will need to look into other options. I strongly suggest you just start working on it... If you run into specific issues, then come back and ask for specific help.

Comment: @DonMag, can you post is as and answer - so I can mark it as one that solved my issue?

Comment: done... Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as per OP)

Two Table Views would be fine.

You can use Collection Views if your content would benefit from Collection View capabilities (but from the layout you've shown, it looks like table views will suffice).

As far as "smooth scrolling" ... `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` should give you satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should to put two child view controllers. Then, the parent view controller add the children view controllers as controllers as you wish. For example, make two tableviewcontrollers and add them into parent's content views.